# Highcharts AreaRange Chart issues with xAxis and last data point label

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I used area range Highcharts but facing certain issues as:

- For X-axis, the chart doesn't start with an initial point rather shows incorrect start tick value(i.e. 2020) instead of 2019.
- Need to show label values for last data point only for each series, attached image below for reference
  [image: areaRange]

Could someone please help me with what do I do to resolve my issues.

Thanks in advance!

For the 1st issue, I tried changing the 'pointStart' attribute value for plotOptions->series but didn't work.

```
"plotOptions": {
        "series": {
            "pointStart": 1546300800000
         }
}
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhadouriyanikhil/a4eqbt62/) link of the chart containing code:

Answer (score 1):

The first issue can be resolved by setting `xAxsi.tickInterval = plotOptions.series.pointInterval`:

```
  xAxis: {
    type: "datetime",
    tickInterval: 31536000000
    ...
  }
```

---

The second issue can be resolved by providing labels formatter callback function that will return only the last series point value. Also, other dataLabels properties have to be set properly (like align, overflow, etc). Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  align: 'left',
  verticalAlign: 'middle',
  padding: 8,
  allowOverlap: true,
  overflow: 'allow',
  crop: false,
  formatter: function() {
    var point = this.point,
      series = this.series;

    if (series.data.length === point.index + 1) {
      return '$' + this.y.toFixed(1);
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2xLevj6y/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.DataLabelsOptionsObject#formatter
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.DataLabelsOptionsObject#align
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.DataLabelsOptionsObject#overflow

Comment: Thanks for the response!
For the first issue, I tried with xAxis.tickInterval, startOnTick, endOnTick, also with min and max attribute but on chart resize it changes, is there any way to fix start and end xAxis values?

Comment: You can use `tickPositioner` or `tickPositions` to set ticks as you like. Check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qgmL3dzn/. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner